# SQL auto change ID of more tables

Tags: sql

How to ensure changing ID in other tables by changing ID in one table? I tried to solve this by creating a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE cars
(
    id integer,
    name varchar,
    cost integer
);

CREATE TABLE garages
(
    id integer,
    car_id integer REFERENCES cars(id),
    size integer
);
```

Does this solve the problem?

Let's say I want to change `id` of one of my cars, does this code also change specific `car_id` in `garages` table?

Comment: No.  It won't automagically change. I recommend you do some research on "Cascade update"

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You must also configure the update rule of the foreign key. If you are using SQL Server the following picture shows you the way. For more information please see [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/delete-cascade-and-update-cascade-in-sql-server-foreign-key/).
[image]

Comment: same applies to most other DBMS, ie MySQL/MariaDB